# Toponogov's theorem in the Alexandrov space with respect to a compact set

Tags: alexandrov-geometry

Let $X$ be an Alexandrov space with curvature $\ge 0$ and $A \subset X$ a compact set. Suppose $p,q\in X$ satisfying $|Ap|=|Aq|=r$ and $p_1,q_1$ are points on the geodesics $Ap,Aq$ respectively such that $|Ap_1|=|Aq_1|=s<r$. Can we prove
$$ 
|p_1q_1| \ge \frac{s}{r}|pq|?
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is true. It can be proved by applying distance estimates to the gradient flow of the function $f=\mathrm{dist}_A^2/2$. See our [draft](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08539).

Comment: Can't you just assume the contrary and take a limit of spaces?

Comment: @dodd you can, but why should it help :)

Comment: The compact will turn into a point, the limit is also of non-negative curvature, geodesics tend to geodesics, so just use the comparison for triangles. Anyway you did not specify the place in your text where the proof is and the draft is long.

Comment: @dodd, there is no limit in the question --- I guess you did not read it carefully.

Comment: I suggested using the limit in the solution. The question does not have limits.

Comment: @dodd I do not think it helps.

Comment: Perhaps it does not. It would help if you include a more concrete reference in your answer. Your draft is 280 page long.

Comment: @dodd Make a search for "distance estimates"

Comment: Can you make this search and report the results here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is also true (with different distortion constant) for Alexandrov space with curvature $\ge k$.

We define
$$
\rho_k(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k}(1-\cos(x\sqrt{k}))\quad &\text{if}\quad k>0,\\
\frac{x^2}{2},\quad &\text{if}\quad k=0,\\
\frac{1}{k}(1-\cosh(x\sqrt{-k}))\quad &\text{if}\quad k<0.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Then it follows from the Toponogov's theorem that for any $p \in X$,
$$
\rho_k(\text{dist}_p)''\le 1-k\rho_k(\text{dist}_p).
$$

By taking the minimum for all $p \in A$, we also have
$$
f''\le 1-kf,
$$
where $f:=\rho_k(\text{dist}_A)$.

Let $\gamma_1(t)$ and $\gamma_2(t)$ be the geodesics of $Ap$ and $Aq$ respectively. It is not hard to see that $\tilde \gamma_1(z):=\gamma_1(t(z))$ and $\tilde \gamma_2(z):=\gamma_2(t(z))$ are the gradient flows of $f$ starting from $p_1$ and $q_1$ respectively. Here the new parameter $z$ is determined by
$$
dz=\frac{dt}{\rho_k'(t)} \quad \text{and} \quad t(0)=s.
$$
If we set $l(t):=|\gamma_1(t)\gamma_2(t)|$, then it follows from the distance estimate of the gradient flow (see Lemma 1.3.3 in this [paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/2006/0011/0001/SDG-2006-0011-0001-a006.pdf)) that
$$
(\log l(t))' \le \frac{1-k\rho_k(t)}{\rho_k'(t)}.
$$

From integration, we obtain
$$
|pq|=l(r) \le \sigma_k(r,s) l(s)=\sigma_k(r,s)|p_1q_1|,
$$
where
$$
\sigma_k(r,s)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(r\sqrt k)}{\sin(s\sqrt k)}\quad &\text{if}\quad k>0,\\
\frac{r}{s},\quad &\text{if}\quad k=0,\\
\frac{\sinh(r\sqrt{-k})}{\sinh(s\sqrt{-k})}\quad &\text{if}\quad k<0.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Where do you use the fact that $A$ is compact?